# AccountManager: First synchronization takes a while sometimes

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager

My application synchronized data using accountmanager. No authentication is used. Sometimes (not always) when I run app for the first time it takes too long for the first synchronization.

Here how I add account

```
private void ensureSyncAccount() {
    final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    String authority = getString(R.string.acc_authority);
    String accountType = getString(R.string.acc_name);
    String accountName = getString(R.string.app_name);

    Account[] existingAccs = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType);
    if (existingAccs.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    Account account = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)) {
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, new Bundle());
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), 60*10);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to add account");
    }
}
```

After a while synchronization starts to work correctly. What can be the reason of synchronization's deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby problem is You requestSync

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, new Bundle());
```

and after this you add periodic sync

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), 60*10);
```

propaby it's waiting to next sync